# Visual Studio SFML Linker Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, visual-studio-2013, sfml

I am new to SFML and when I tried to compile a basic program, I'd get this error

> Error  2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void >__cdecl sf::sleep(class sf::Time)" (__imp_?sleep@sf@@YAXVTime@1@@Z) referenced in> >function _main   C:\Users\asd\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenGL\OpenGL\Source.obj OpenGL

Here's the code:

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#define SFML_STATIC

int main()
{
  sf::sleep(sf::seconds(1.f));
  return 0;
}
```

I also linked the sfml-windows-s.lib and sfml-system-s.lib

Comment: Perhaps try to define SFML_STATIC before including? Not sure though

Comment: @ComradeBearabyte It's not a problem with the include files. Just with the Libraries, but I'll try it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to define SFML_STATIC as a preprocessor instead of inside the code.