# Configuring SFML on Visual Studio manually

Tags: visual-studio, libraries, sfml

This Q&A post comes from [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162014/unresolved-external-symbol-lnk-2001/34162119#34162119) and [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015154/visual-studio-sfml-linker-error) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329948/visual-studio-linker-error-while-linking-sfml-2-1) related to [sfml](/questions/tagged/sfml) library when people try to configure manually their VS projects. Sometimes answers aren't complete or they're too specific.

I would like to compile in a single post how to configure VS to be able to use the SFML library both statically and dynamically.

So:

**1. How can I configure my VS project with [sfml](/questions/tagged/sfml) libraries *dynamically*, in a general way?**

**2. How can I configure my VS project with [sfml](/questions/tagged/sfml) libraries *statically*, in a general way?**

Comment: For MSVC I use `vcpkg`: `vcpkg integrate install` and `vcpkg install sfml`. After that every new projects VS will automatically include and link SFML for you. Of course it doesn't link statically.

Comment: @tntxtnt I'll have a look on that, thanks! Normally I like to install `SFML` via NuGet packages, but not everybody use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First, I recommend carefully follow the [SFML tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/start-vc.php) about configuring the library in Visual Studio, if something goes wrong, then check this answer.

---

I will divide this answer in two groups, how to configure [sfml](/questions/tagged/sfml) **as a dynamic library** and how to do it **as a static library**.

#### Common steps

1. Let's create a VS project (I will use VS2013 and SFML 2.5.1, but it's pretty much the same with other versions). Create it as *ConsoleApplication* and check *Empty Project*.
2. Download [sfml](/questions/tagged/sfml) [libraries](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php), latest stable version preferably, selecting your corresponding system (in my case *Visual C++ 12 (2013) - 64-bit*). Extract this file where your `.vcxproj` file is. This will create a folder named *SFML-X.X.X* depending on your version.
3. Download the [external libraries](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/tree/master/extlibs), in my case [64 bits](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/tree/master/extlibs/libs-msvc-universal/x64) version. Create a folder called *extlib* inside the library folder and place this external libraries there.
4. Create a `main.cpp` file, and paste the example code from [SFML tutorials](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/start-vc.php).

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### SFML As Dynamic Library

1. Go to *Build->Configuration Manager*. If you are using a 64 bits library, first you should create a new Solution Platform. Click on *Active Solutions Platform->New*, select *x64* copying from *Win32* configuration. I prefer to **uncheck** *Create new project platforms*.
2. Create **Debug-Dynamic** and **Release-Dynamic** compilation profiles. With your active solution platform selected, click on *Configuration* (of the project) and *New*. You can call it *Debug-Dynamic* and copy it from Debug configuration (also, uncheck *Create new...*). Repeat creating a **Release-Dynamic** configuration.
3. Open *Project  Properties->Debugging*. Select **Debug-Dynamic** configuration and modify field *Environment* with this value `PATH=$(ProjectDir)\SFML-X.X.X\bin;%PATH%`. This will indicate VS where `.dll` libraries can be found.
4. Over *C/C++* section, modify *Additional include directories* field by adding this path `$(ProjectDir)\SFML-X.X.X\include`. This will indicate VS where `.hpp` files are located.
5. On *Linker* section, modify *Additional library directories* field by adding this path `$(ProjectDir)\SFML-X.X.X\lib`. This will indicate VS where `.lib` files can be found.
6. Finally, on *Linker->Input*, modify *Additional dependencies* field by adding all `.lib` files needed:

```
    sfml-audio-d.lib
    sfml-graphics-d.lib
    sfml-network-d.lib
    sfml-system-d.lib
    sfml-window-d.lib
```

<sup>Note `-d` suffix to indicate *debug libraries*</sup>

7. Repeat steps 3 to 6 with **Release-Dynamic** configuration. **Note**, on step 6, library files doesn't have `-d` suffix, because they're release libraries

#### SFML As Static Library

1. Go to *Build->Configuration Manager*. Create **Debug-Static** and **Release-Static** compilation profiles. With your active solution platform selected, click on *Configuration* (of the project) and *New*. You can call it *Debug-Static* and copy it from Debug configuration (also, uncheck *Create new...*). Repeat creating a **Release-Static** configuration.
2. Open *Project Properties* and select *Debug-Static* configuration. Over *C/C++* section, modify *Additional include directories* field by adding this path `$(ProjectDir)\SFML-X.X.X\include`. This will indicate VS where `.hpp` files are located.
3. On *C/C++* section->Preprocessor*, modify *Preprocessor definitions* field by adding `SFML_STATIC` definition. This will indicate preprocessor that SFML will be statically compiled.
4. Over *Linker* section, modify *Additional library directories* field by adding this paths `$(ProjectDir)\SFML-X.X.X\extlib;$(ProjectDir)\SFML-X.X.X\lib;`. This will indicate VS where `.lib` files from *external sources* and from SFML can be found.
5. Finally, on *Linker->Input* section, modify *Additional dependencies* field with all `.lib` files needed:

```
    sfml-audio-s-d.lib
    sfml-graphics-s-d.lib
    sfml-network-s-d.lib
    sfml-system-s-d.lib
    sfml-window-s-d.lib
    flac.lib
    freetype.lib
    ogg.lib
    openal32.lib
    opengl32.lib
    vorbis.lib
    vorbisenc.lib
    vorbisfile.lib
    winmm.lib
    gdi32.lib
    ws2_32.lib
```

<sup>Note `-d` suffix to indicate *debug libraries*</sup>

<sup>Note2 `-s` suffix to indicate *static libraries*</sup>

6. Repeat steps 2 to 5 with **Release-Static** configuration. **Note**, on step 5, library files doesn't have `-d` suffix, because they're release libraries, but they'll keep `-s` suffix.