# Integrating SFML with Visual C++ 2017

Tags: visual-c++, sfml

I tried integrating SFML with my visual c++ project, careful to follow the procedure on the SFML website and received 2 main types of errors. The first offending line in the file rect.inl is :

**T minX = std::min(left, static_cast(left + width));**

The description of the first kind of error reads:

'(': illegal token on right side of '::' c:\libs\c++\sfml-2.5.1-windows-vc15-32-bit\sfml-2.5.1\include\sfml\graphics\rect.inl   81

the other kind of error is:

**template 
Rect::Rect() :
left  (0),
top   (0),
width (0),
height(0)
{
} :**

Rect is not a template  ChessApplication    C:\Libs\c++\SFML-2.5.1-windows-vc15-32-bit\SFML-2.5.1\include\SFML\Graphics\Rect.inl    28

**My project setup is:**

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.9.9
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.9+28307.518
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

Additional Library Directories: C:\Libs\c++\SFML-2.5.1-windows-vc15-32-bit\SFML-2.5.1\lib

Additional Include Directories: C:\Libs\c++\SFML-2.5.1-windows-vc15-32-bit\SFML-2.5.1\include

Additional dependencies (debug): sfml-window-d.lib;sfml-graphics-d.lib;sfml-system-d.lib;sfml-audio-d.lib

Additional dependencies (release): sfml-window.lib;sfml-graphics.lib;sfml-system.lib;sfml-audio.lib

I used dynamic linking, placing sfml-xxx-2.dll files in the same directory as the .sln project.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54791159/3195314

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing the precompiled header "stadfx.h" from my classes.