# SFML library not importing for C++

Tags: c++, syntax-error, sfml

I have tried to use SFML but it does not work
The error is to do with importing the library, i couldn't figure out to install it, i tried multiple tutorials, but all have failed so far.

```
#include <iostr>

#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

//using namespace sf;

int main() {
    //window
    sf::Window window(sf::Videomode(640, 480), "My first game", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style:: Close);
    sf::Event ev;

    //Game loop
    while (window.pollEvent(ev)) {
        //Event polling
        switch () {

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Errors and code in VS]

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: What is `<iostr>` supposed to be?

Comment: You probably forgot to set the "Additional Include Directories" setting for your project or you set it to the wrong folder. If you got that wrong you probably also need to set the linker settings

Comment: I did do those to the right directory

Comment: im on windows btw

Comment: i forgot to finish typing <iostream>

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54791159/3195314